# Create relation between large amout of nodes in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the the following graph from this question: [Cypher 2 not using schema index with OR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746293/cypher-2-not-using-schema-index-with-or-operator):

```
CREATE 
(:Application {Name: "Test Application", Aliases: ["Test", "App", "TestProject"]}),
(:Application {Name: "Another Application", Aliases: ["A-App", "XYZ", "XYProject"]}),
(:Application {Name: "Database X", Aliases: ["DB-App", "DB", "DB-Project"]}),
(:System {Name: "Server1", Application: "TestProject"}),
(:System {Name: "Server2", Application: "Test Application"}),
(:System {Name: "Server3", Application: "another App"}),
(:System {Name: "Server4", Application: "Some Database"}),
(:System {Name: "Server5", Application: "App"}),
(:System {Name: "Server6", Application: "App XY"}),
(:System {Name: "Server7", Application: "App DB"}),
(:System {Name: "Server8", Application: "Test"}),
(:System {Name: "Server9", Application: "TestProject"}),
(:System {Name: "Server10", Application: "test"}),
(:System {Name: "Server11", Application: "App XY"});

CREATE INDEX ON :Application(Name);
CREATE INDEX ON :Application(Aliases);

CREATE INDEX ON :System(Application);
```

But with 900 `Application` and 200.000 `System`nodes.

I added a new alias (e.g. "Test MiniApp") to one of the applications (that will finally match ~27.000 new `System` nodes in the production database) and run the following query:

```
MATCH (a:Application { Name: "Test Application"})
WITH a
MATCH (s:System)
WHERE s.Application IN (a.Aliases + a.Name)
AND NOT (a)-[:InstalledOn]->(s)
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:InstalledOn]->(s)
```

This query is using the schema index on the production database (tested with PROFILE) but runs simply too long, ~5 minutes. I wonder why it takes so long to create a relation for ~27k nodes that are found with an index.

Neo4j 2.1.6 runs with default settings on Linux system (SLES 11) with 96 GB RAM.

**EDIT**
The above query just return a single node of type `Application` and is only executed when a application is renamed and/or when an alias is added/removed. Since both entities are coming from external systems at any time i cannot only use the case where a new system could directly related to an application, because it may not exist during the import time. So when someone add a new alias, etc. to an application i need to find all matching systems and create that relation.

Comment: How many applications match {Name: "Test Application"}?  Just one? Seems here you're looking through most :InstalledOn relationships on most :Systems, which could be slow (200K of them).  I'm afraid that since you're looking for things which are *not connected* to a particular node this inherently takes some time since clearly you can't exploit relationships to traverse to those nodes.

Comment: Hi, there is just one Application node with this name and/or alias.

Comment: You should probably create relationships from `:Application` to `:System` as needed to capture that relationship (`where s.Application IN (a.Aliases + Name)`) - checking a property against a long list of possibilities across 200k `System` nodes seems like something you don't want to recompute every time, even with an index.  Maybe you don't even need the `Application` property on `:System`?

Comment: Well that the use case, if the application is updated (e.g. name changed and/or alias added/removed) that query is executed. Its not for searching. Problem here is that both data is coming from external systems at any time. Updating a new/change system its search because you're only looking for 900 applications, but when a application changes i need that query to create relations.

Comment: My point is that neo4j tends to make relationship traversal fast; matching property values is slower. If you can maintain the property value list, you could also maintain a list of rels that captures the same data. I don't know your model so I can't say for sure, but it's a frequently observed anti-pattern to try and join node populations by some value, when rels exist to do that (and faster). Again, you're trying to find stuff that's *not* connected too in this query; consider how to exploit rels in your model to simplify what you're asking.

Comment: I added a edit, why i don't know the relation during adding of systems into the graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72053/discussion-between-dna-and-frobberofbits).

Answer (score 0):

The check for `NOT (a)-[:InstalledOn]->(s)` in the `WHERE` clause should not be necessary, since `CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:InstalledOn]->(s)` will do the same check for you automatically. Essentially, you are doing the same check twice.

Does this speed up things?

```
MATCH (a:Application { Name: "Test Application"}), (s:System)
WHERE s.Application IN (a.Aliases + a.Name)
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:InstalledOn]->(s)
```

Comment: The ```MATCH x,y WHERE ...``` syntax will not use the schema syntax and NodeByLabel instead .. very slow.